# flexbox two columns and footer with scrollbar per column if needed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have two columns and a footer, such that the overall size is `100vh`, and the footer is relatively small so should not have a scrollbar. The columns should take up all the remaining space above the footer. One column has a lot of content and so should have a scrollbar (appearing dynamically).

This is the closest I could get:

```html
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 50%">column 1</div>
      <div
        style="
          overflow-y: auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-basis: 50%;
          flex-direction: column;
        "
      >
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; color: white; display: flex">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: min-height:0 on the second flex container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently the impossible to guess answer is having `overflow: hidden` on the immediate parent.

```html
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow: hidden">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 50%">column 1</div>
      <div
        style="
          overflow-y: auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-basis: 50%;
          flex-direction: column;
        "
      >
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; color: white; display: flex">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```